# UITableViewCell gets reselected when scrolled back on screen

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've run into an issue while implementing a `UITableView` in an iOS app I'm working on(iOS SDK 4.2).  If I tap a cell in the Table View, and then scroll the view so that the cell leaves the screen, when it comes back into view the most recently selected cell has been reselected.

To test this I created a new View Based Application project, dragged out a `UITableView` in Interface Builder, and set the view controller as the table view's data source and delegate, and put the following code in the view controller:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *) tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {
    return 12;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"aCellID";

    UITableViewCell *aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (!aCell) {
        aCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];
    }

    aCell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row +1];

    return aCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *aCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [aCell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
}
```

When running this(in simulator or on device) if I were to tap any cell(cell 12 for example), it would be selected and deselected.  After this, with no cells in the table currently selected, if I scroll the view so that the most recently selected cell(12 in this case) leaves the screen, it will be selected again when it reappears.

Is this the intended default behavior for `UITableView`?  Or possibly an error in my implementation?  What would be best way to deselect this cell in this situation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It took me asking to figure this one out myself:

My problem was using the `UITableViewCell` method `setSelected:` instead of using the `UITableView` method `deselectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: are you able to still reproduce the animation where it selects it for a brief moment and then deselects it right after?

Comment: @cr54 Yes, you can still get that animation effect like this:
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}